# Paypal page not displaying in the iframe tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, payment-gateway

I am newbie to paypal. I want to integrate the direct payment in the same website. I have read the pdf file (Website payment Pro Hosted) and put some code in the html page. I have posted the code like:

```
<iframe name="hss_iframe" width="570px" height="540px"></iframe>
<form style="display:none" target="hss_iframe" name="form_iframe" method="post" action="https://securepayments.paypal.com/cgi-bin/acquiringweb">
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_hosted-payment">
   <input type="hidden" name="subtotal" value="50">
   <input type="hidden" name="business" value="HNZ3QZMCPBAAA">
   <input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale">
   <input type="hidden" name="template" value="templateD">
   <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://yourwebsite.com/receipt_page.html">
</form>
```

but the iframe is not loading. What am I doing wrong. Am I missing any fields. I am displaying the iframe in button click.

Comment: is this Adaptive payment method? What is hss_iframe from PayPal or from your site page?

Comment: Actually i have pasted the code from the pdf file. I want to adaptive payment only

Comment: Using adaptive you need to include the script in your page https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js

Comment: can you be more specific. sorry about this.

Comment: Is the account HNZ3QZMCPBAAA signed up for the product? Try to open the page outside the iframe; does it return an error?

Comment: No how can i sign up for the product and how can i get the bussiness value

Comment: @Robert How can i sign up for the product. How can i get the bussiness value of the paypal

Comment: That depends on your country - the product you're using (Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution) may not be available in your country. Have a look at https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/website-payments-pro-hosted-solution#availability-and-fees which also has links to sign up for each respective country.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only the code as we see it, then is do nothing, is a hidden form that is going to fill the `iframe` when you submit it!

At the end (or somewhere) you must have also the `submit()` of this form as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.form_iframe.submit();
</script>
```

Comment: Yah actually i have did this. But where did we get the form details like bussiness